# How to optimize dynamically created PDF for search engines?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, seo

My site includes a repository/library of PDF documents which are generated on the fly with stories from a database.

These docs are accessible through a link, e.g. /library.aspx?docid=1234 which is generally distributed via email or social media sites.

How can I get the content of these documents indexed on Google Search (or any other search engine, for that matter)?

Ideally, I guess, the individual stories in the database would be trawled by Google and the link would be to the document url above.

Answer (score 0):

Google allows you to submit your URLs.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1352276

To get it on all search engines, I would create pages with links to the PDFs and include the links in my sitemap.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That would ensure indexing of the PDF's content alright, but I don't want the links to point to the PDF file itself. I want the visitors to land on the branded page which has the PDF embedded as '<object>'.

Comment: http://forums.seochat.com/google-optimization-7/embedded-pdf-crawlability-422312.html